# Правильно составить регулярное выражение для строки, содержащей скобки

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, json

есть строка

```
"128728581": {"vehicleType": "vehicleType", "isAlive": true, "name": "name", "clanAbbrev": "", "team": 1, "events": {}, "isTeamKiller": false},
```

пытался сделать так

```
@"""\d+""[^}]+"
```

но проблема в том что в "events" есть закрывающая скобка.
как вариант ,сделал так

```
@"""\d+""[^}]+[^}]+events[^,]+[^}]+"
```

но просто измениться строка и event не будет то не будет работать, как правильнее сделать?

И еще один вопрос : 
нужно из той же строки достать набор цифр в начале, сделал так

```
string[] arr = reg.Match(parse).ToString().Split('"');

reg = new Regex(@"\d+");

foreach (string val in arr)
{
    if (reg.IsMatch(val)) {
        id = int.Parse(val);
        break;
    }
}
```

но как то не самый оптимальный вариант (мне кажется).

То что это JSON, я знаю и то что есть спец либы для разбора, но мне нужно из большого документа вытащить строки с нужным мне id, а потом их парсить.

П.с почему не работает тэг code, не могу понять как код подсвечивать?

Comment: @VladD, 2010 и там в настройках не нашел .NET 4.5 только .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте подходящий инструментарий для задачи. Если вы хотите распарсить JSON, пользуйтесь JSON-парсером. Например, [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/).

Хотя современные регулярные выражения и являются Тьюринг-полными, известно, что правильно (то есть с учётом всех возможных подводных камней) парсить рекурсивные грамматики на них неоправданно сложно. Делайте правильно, сэкономьте геморрой и время на более приятные дела.

---

Если вам посчастливилось работать с .NET 4.5, там есть [встроенный JSON-парсер](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonvalue.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Да просто не хочется использовать парсер для поиска пары строк и выборки из них id...

Comment: @cyber_ua: Не обольщайтесь. Ваша задача не "найти пару строк", а "распарсить формат JSON". Решайте задачу адекватно условию самой задачи. Есть куча граничных случаев, типа пробелов перед/после двоеточия, заэкранированных двойных кавычек в строке, разбиения на строки в неожиданных местах и т. п. Вы точно хотите учесть всё это в вашем регулярном выражении?

Comment: >Если вам посчастливилось работать с .NET 4.5, там есть встроенный JSON-парсер.

хм, пытаюсь подключать using System.Json; пишет такое имя отсутствует.  у меня стоит net 4.5 - ошибся ,у меня  какого то черта нет 4.5)

Comment: @cyber_ua: а вы подключили System.Runtime.Serialization.dll?

Comment: Да, и я не могу понять этой фишки:
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-N3WSNSUpAS8/UMNGpxnKJmI/AAAAAAAAAJU/19TApgYwB-8/s1257/2.jpg
установщик предлагает востановить (значить net 4.5 есть), а в папке net его нет, странно.

Comment: @cyber_ua: Хм, может быть, кто-то некорректно снёс эту версию? Попробуйте переустановить. Или снести и установить по-новому.

Comment: @VladD, уже пробывал, и к компу доступ токлько у меня а я не сносил ее точно.

Comment: @cyber_ua: Хм. А Visual Studio какой версии? Если 2012, просто выберите тип проекта ".NET 4.5", должно работать.